# Sorting pairs of teams with non-repeating | Round-robin tournament

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sports-league-scheduling-problem

I'm generating schedule for the tournament. Each team should play exactly 8 games. Number of teams 2 < n < 36

For sorting teams into pairs I'm using Round Robin algorithm to get a table, example of 6 teams :

[image]

Then I convert it into the set of pairs:

```
1   4
2   3
3   2
4   1
5   6
6   5
1   2
2   1
3   5
4   6
5   3
6   4
...
```

The question is how to sort this set, in order to get schedule, where the same team can't play 2 games in a row. But if it's impossible, minimize the number of exceptions.

---

Example with new algorithm:

[image]

Comment: I think you mean `2 < n < 36`

Comment: yes, exactly, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to start an approach to answer this question. If asked, I can leave it as a *community wiki*, so that people can make edits to improve this answer.

[<kbd>Wikipedia Round-robin Tournament Scheduling Algorithm</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm)

Let's start with the case of 8 teams. 
[T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, T<sub>3</sub>, T<sub>4</sub>, T<sub>5</sub>, T<sub>6</sub>, T<sub>7</sub>, T<sub>8</sub>]

Let us try to look at this problem like so..

T<sub>1</sub> T<sub>2</sub> T<sub>3</sub> T<sub>4</sub> 
T<sub>5</sub> T<sub>6</sub> T<sub>7</sub> T<sub>8</sub>

So, now. Matches -> [(1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8)].

Rotate the list clock-wise, but keep position of T<sub>1</sub> fixed.

T<sub>1</sub> T<sub>5</sub> T<sub>2</sub> T<sub>3</sub>  
T<sub>6</sub> T<sub>7</sub> T<sub>8</sub> T<sub>4</sub>

So, now. Matches -> [`(1,5), (2,6), (3,7), (4,8)`, (1,6), (5,7), (2,8), (3,4)].

In this case, there will be 7 possible rotations before duplication start to occur. In a traditional round-robin tournament, there are `(n/2)*(n-1)` games, where `n` is the number of teams. This should work regardless of the number of teams involved. [If you encounter `n%2 == 1`, put an `X` to make the set even and continue as normal; one team will sit out on one match].

**If you need to ensure that each team *must* play 8 games, make *exactly* 8 rotations when the number of teams is even.**

This method correspondingly ensure, that given a sufficient number of teams, same teams won't play back to back games.

**Edit**.

Let's start with the case of 3 teams.
[T<sub>1</sub>, T<sub>2</sub>, T<sub>3</sub>]

Let us try to look at this problem like so..

T<sub>1</sub> T<sub>2</sub> 
T<sub>3</sub> X

So, now. Matches -> [(1,3), (2,X)].

Rotate the list clock-wise, but keep position of T<sub>1</sub> fixed.

T<sub>1</sub> T<sub>3</sub> 
X   T<sub>2</sub>

So, now. Matches -> [`(1,3), (2,X)`, (1,X), (3,2)].

Next case, Matches -> [`(1,3), (2,X), (1,X), (3,2)`, (1,2), (X,3)].

Next case, Matches -> [`(1,3), (2,X), (1,X), (3,2), (1,2), (X,3)`, (1,3), (2,X)].

....

Matches -> [`(1,3), (2,X), (1,X), (3,2), (1,2), (X,3)`, `(1,3), (2,X), (1,X), (3,2), (1,2), (X,3)`, `(1,3), (2,X), (1,X), (3,2), (1,2), (X,3)`, `(1,3), (2,X), (1,X), (3,2), (1,2), (X,3)`, `(1,3), (2,X), (1,X), (3,2), (1,2), (X,3)`].

1 -> [`3,X,2`,`3,X,2`,`3,X,2`,`3,X,2`] 
 
2 -> [`X,3,1`,`X,3,1`,`X,3,1`,`X,3,1`] 
3 -> [`1,2,X`,`1,2,X`,`1,2,X`,`1,2,X`]

If you notice the pattern, you will see that under these conditions, it is impossible to ensure that teams don't play back-to-back games. It required 12 rotations to get each team to have played 8 games. I am trying to come up with a formula and will update this post accordingly.

Comment: @DmitrijsBambulaks Sure thing, buddy :)

Comment: There is still a question... it works fine with the even number of teams. But when it's odd, i'm missing a number of games (which should be 8) because of not including games with the X to the final schedule

Comment: could you add the test case? the value of `n`, and the state of the list?

Comment: @DmitrijsBambulaks Apologies for the delay. I was traveling. Made an update. Couple more things to add. Working on it.

Comment: Yes, it is imposible to get no-repeating with the odd number of teams... But probably i will solve this problem by merging in pairs games with X